# Setting markers in plot according to values in list

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Say I have a list that looks like this:

```
list_a = [[1.2, 0.5, 3.1,...], [7.3, 1.5, 3.9,...], [100, 200, 150, ...]]
```

The first and second sub-lists in that list define my `(x, y)` values which I want to plot. The **third** sub-list contains values associated to each `(x, y)` point (say a certain property). These *associated values* can only be one of three values: `100, 150, 200`; which means that each `(x, y)` pair has either a `100`, a `150` or a `200`value attached to it.

I want to plot these `(x, y)` points in a scatter plot but giving to each of them a marker according to the values in this third list.

So, I'd want for example (not real code of course):

```
if list_a[2][item] == 100 then use marker = 'o' (circle marker)
if list_a[2][item] == 150 then use marker = 's' (square marker)
if list_a[2][item] == 200 then use marker = '^' (triangle_up marker)
```

The only way I can think of doing this is re-packaging `list_a` so that all `(x, y)` pairs associated with the same value in the third list are moved to its own list, like so:

```
list_100 =[[subset of x values], [subset of y values]]
list_150 =[[subset of x values], [subset of y values]]
list_200 =[[subset of x values], [subset of y values]]
```

and then plot each list separately, setting the appropriate marker each time:

```
plot.scatter(list_100[0], list_100[1], marker='o')
plot.scatter(list_150[0], list_150[1], marker='s')
plot.scatter(list_200[0], list_200[1], marker='^')
```

I'd like to know if there's a way of doing this without needing to re-package the original list and then setting several separated plots for each value in the third sub-list.

Comment: I don't understand how the third list connects with the first two.  Please clarify.  E.g., how would you create the `list_100`, which of the (x, y) points would it contain?

Comment: I've re-factored the question a little bit, is it better now?

Comment: The way `scatter` works underneath each call can only have one marker shape (which can then be sized and colored).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this:

```
list_a = [[1.2, 0.5, 3.1,...], [7.3, 1.5, 3.9,...], [100, 200, 150, ...]]
import numpy as np
x = np.asarray(list_a[0])
y = np.asarray(list_a[1])
m = np.asarray(list_a[2])
mrk = {100:'o',150:'s',200:'^'}
for key,value in mrk.items():
    s1 = (m==key)
    plt.scatter(x[s1],y[s1],marker=value)
```

this is very efficient, indeed.

Comment: As a side note, if you aren't setting the size or color of the points, using `plot` with no connecting line is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this do?  It rearranges your lists, so it's not as efficient as you'd probably want it, but I suppose it will work for you.

```
list_a = [[1.2, 0.5, 3.1, 4.0, 2.3, 6.7],
          [7.3, 1.5, 3.9, 2.7, 1.4, 9.1],
          [100, 200, 150, 200, 100, 100]]

markers = [(100, 'o'), (150, 's'), (200, '^')]

list_r = zip(*list_a)

for value, marker in markers:
  def f(p):
    return p[2] == value
  sublist_r = filter(f, list_r)
  sublist = zip(*sublist_r)
  plot.scatter(sublist[0], sublist[1], marker=marker)
```

The advantage over the smaller solution of @roshan is that it calls `plot.scatter` once for each type of marker that you have, not once for every point.

Comment: This should work, but it rearranges the list which is what I intended to avoid. If there's no other answer given without the need to rearrange the list, I'll mark this one as accepted.

Comment: I'm not familiar with matlab's API, so I don't know if what you're asking is possible.  If `plot.scatter` is all that there is, I suppose you'll have to rearrange.

Answer (score 1):

As you have only three associated value and you know corresponding plot-value,
so map each associated value to plot-value :

```
plot_map = { 100:'o' ,150:'s' , 200:'^' }
```

now, as each sublist will have equal element:

```
for i in range(len(list_a[0])):
    plot.scatter(list_a[0][i], list_a[1][i], plot_map[list_a[2][i]])
```

Comment: This has the drawback that it calls `plot` for every point and it gets *really slow* for large datasets.